# Breaking time in hours equivalent , ios?

Tags: ios, datetime, nsmutablearray

I have an array of time strings as follows:

```
 Time-Array = {10:00 AM, 10:15 AM ,10:30 AM,10:45 AM,11:00 AM,11:15 AM,11:30 AM,11:45 AM,12:00 PM,

 3:00 PM,3:15 PM, 3:30 PM, 3:45 PM,4:00 PM,

 7:00 PM,7:15 PM, 7:30 PM. 7:45 PM, 8:00 PM, 8:15 PM, 8:30 PM, 8:45 PM, 9:00 PM, 9:15 PM, 9:30 PM, 9:45 PM, 10:00 PM}
```

I want to break this in to a single time where the output will be as:

```
10:00 AM - 12: 00 PM

3:00 PM - 4:00 PM

7:00 PM - 10: 00 PM
```

This is so far I have tried

```
NSLog(@"------****%@",TTTimeArray);
        NSString *sss=[TTTimeArray objectAtIndex:0];
        int addTime=0;
        NSString *dateOutPut;
        NSLog(@"sss------****%@",sss);
        timeArray=[NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i=0;i<[TTTimeArray count]-1;i++)
        {
            if ([[TTTimeArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:sss]) {
                [timeArray addObject:[TTTimeArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                 NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
                [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
                [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
                addTime=15;
                NSDate *dateInput=[formatter dateFromString:sss];
                dateInput=[dateInput dateByAddingTimeInterval:addTime*60];
                dateOutPut=[formatter stringFromDate:dateInput];
                dateOutPut=[dateOutPut uppercaseString];
                sss=dateOutPut;
                NSLog(@"OutputDate= %@",dateOutPut);

            }
            NSLog(@"iii------****%d",i);
 //                else if ([[TTTimeArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:sss]) {
//                    
//                }
         }
```

I am able to get 10:00 AM - 12:00 PM. But after that I am confused what should I do next to get the the next output.

Comment: Are these periods fixed? I assume, you always want 10 - 12, 3 - 4 and 7 - 10, am I right? Or will these periods change?

Comment: These are not fixed. This is a web service response in interval of 15 mins.

Comment: But what is your rule to summarize periods? currently you are doing it the "dirty" way (just loop over everything and decide, if it's relevant for you or not) - perhaps there is a more elegant way with [NSArray objectAtIndex:] if we know, what your rules are.